# KDB Query with OR condition like in SQL

Tags: kdb, q-lang

In SQL I may write query with logical (true and true) or (true and true), i.e:

```
select * from t1 inner join t2 on ... where (t1.a != t2.a and t1.b != t2.b) or (t1. != t2.a and t1.b != t2.b)
```

when I try to do it in Q like this

```
select from ej[....] where (t1.a != t2.a and t1.b != t2.b) or (t1. != t2.a and t1.b != t2.b)
```

it fails to compile.

I have also tried this

```
(t1.a != t2.a and t1.b != t2.b) or (t1. != t2.a and t1.b != t2.b)
```

but it doesn't return the correct result either

How to query it in KDB?

Answer (score 2):

Try this (in pseudo-code):

```
( (t1.a != t2.a) and (t1.b != t2.b) ) or ( (t1.a != t2.a) and (t1.b != t2.b) )
```

Kdb/Q reads *left-of-right* so it treats

```
t1.a != t2.a and t1.b != t2.b
```

as

```
t1.a != (t2.a and t1.b != t2.b)
```

rather than

```
(t1.a != t2.a) and (t1.b != t2.b)
```

unless you explicity use brackets